# Spring Batch - JobRepository Configuration not required?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I'm following the official [Spring Batch starter guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/).
I have a basic question. I get an error, that the Bean JobRepository is not defined.
The guide really never creates that bean. It is used in the importUserJob and step1. How is that possible?
Shouldn't they create that Bean to configure the db etc.? This is the Code from the Guide.
The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing/tree/main/complete).

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    // tag::readerwriterprocessor[]
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
            .name("personItemReader")
            .resource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"))
            .delimited()
            .names(new String[]{"firstName", "lastName"})
            .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
                setTargetType(Person.class);
            }})
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
        return new PersonItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
            .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
            .sql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobRepository jobRepository,
            JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return new JobBuilder("importUserJob", jobRepository)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(step1)
            .end()
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository,
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {
        return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
            .<Person, Person> chunk(10, transactionManager)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
    }
}
```

`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JobRepository` will be auto-configured as soon as you add the dependency:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch
```

This will also create a few tables in the database configured for your application. Like `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` and `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION`.

After proper auto-configuration `JobRepositoty` bean can be autowired in any component or configuration class. Also as a constructor parameter like in your code snippet of `BatchConfiguration`.

Comment: Greatly appreciate if you can have a look at my issue mentioned here,
https://stackoverflow.com/q/76597033/8181663

Answer (score 1):

It is Spring Boot that creates that bean and adds it to the application context. Therefore, it is possible to autowire it in bean definition methods and use it to configure jobs and steps.

For more details, please check the section about Spring Batch in Spring Boot's documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.batch.specifying-a-data-source).

Comment: Greatly appreciate if you can have a look at my issue mentioned here,
https://stackoverflow.com/q/76597033/8181663